# Ovveride shell for commands in ssh config (~/.ssh/config)

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, openssh

So i have a ssh config file for my user that is using `Match exec` in it to get some matches on IP :

```
Match exec "echo %h | grepcidr 192.168.12.0/20  &>/dev/null "
  User         ubuntu
  ProxyCommand          ssh my-bastion -W %h:%
  IdentityFile          ~/.ssh/target.pem
```

This works fine on my host, but i've tried to launch it on a container where i have openssh-client installed, however the ssh connexion fails because it considers that the command has succeded (even when i'm not targeting the network), so it will try to go through the bastion

```
debug1: Executing command: 'echo my.host.com | grepcidr 192.168.12.0/20 &>/dev/null '
debug3: command returned status 0
```

On my host it returns

```
debug1: Executing command: 'echo my.host.com | grepcidr 192.168.12.0/20 &>/dev/null '
debug3: command returned status 1
```

Which should be what the containers ssh command return

I've been digging and it turns out that the ssh command in the container is launched using `sh -c` whereas the ssh command launched on my host is `bash -c`
I can confirm that this is the cause, by testing both on the command line and checking the return of the command with `echo $?`

Is there any way to specify to the ssh command to only use `bash` ?

I can override the `SHELL` env vars at the beginning of the command line

```
SHELL=/bin/bash ssh user@my.host.com
```

But my goal is to use ansible behind all that so i'd like to ovveride the shell for all SSH.

Answer (score 1):

You can either specify an alternative command that begins with `bash -c`, or drop your Bashism (namely `&>` stdout-and-stderr redirection).

The `Match exec` uses something like the `system()` C function, so it's up to the runtime system (C library) to decide which shell it provides. On most Unix systems it translates to `sh -c` plus the whole command line. You can't change this part.